# Count number of results for a particular word on Twitter

Tags: asp.net, api, twitter, screen-scraping, search

To further a personal project of mine, I have been pondering how to count the number of results for a user specified word on [Twitter](http://www.twitter.com).  I have used their API extensively, but have not been able to come up with an efficient or even halfway practical way to count the occurrences of a particular word.  The actual results are not critical, just the overall count.  I'll keep scratching my head.  Any ideas or direction pointing would be most appreciated.

e.g. http://search.twitter.com/search?q=tomatoes

Comment: Hey @Chris, Did you found solution? I'm facing same issue to get number of count for specific searched word.

Answer (score 2):

I'm able to go back about a week. I start my search with the parameters that Adam posted and then key off of the smallest id in the set of search results, like so,
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?lang=en&q=iphone&rpp=100&max_id=
where max_id = the min(id) of the 100 results I just pulled.

Comment: could you please update me with availability of this thing in their new api v 1.1, because the link you provided isn't working :(

Answer (score 0):

net but I have made recursive function to call search query again and again until I don't find word "page=" in result.

Comment: I thought that result, but it won't be *good* way when searching some word if its about very famous person or so. :(