# Plotting a word-cloud by date for a twitter search result? (using R)

Tags: database, r, visualization, twitter

I wish to search twitter for a word (let's say #google), and then be able to generate a tag cloud of the words used in twitts, but according to dates (for example, having a moving window of an hour, that moves by 10 minutes each time, and shows me how different words gotten more often used throughout the day).

I would appreciate any help on how to go about doing this regarding: resources for the information, code for the programming (R is the only language I am apt in using) and ideas on visualization.  Questions:

1. How do I get the information?

   In R, I found that the twitteR package has the searchTwitter command.  But I don't know how big an "n" I can get from it.  Also, It doesn't return the dates in which the twitt originated from.

   I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580369/count-number-of-results-for-a-particular-word-on-twitter) that I could get until 1500 twitts, but this requires me to do the parsing manually (which leads me to step 2).  Also, for my purposes, I would need tens of thousands of twitts.  Is it even possible to get them in retrospect?? (for example, asking older posts each time through the API URL ?)  If not, there is the more general question of how to create a personal storage of twitts on your home computer? (a question which might be better left to another SO thread - although any insights from people here would be very interesting for me to read)
2. How to parse the information (in R)? I know that R has functions that could help from  the rcurl and twitteR packages.  But I don't know which, or how to use them.  Any suggestions would be of help.
3. How to analyse?  how to remove all the "not interesting" words?  I found that the "tm" package in R has [this example](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tm/vignettes/tm.pdf):

   reuters <- tm_map(reuters, removeWords, stopwords("english"))

   Would this do the trick?  I should I do something else/more ?

   Also, I imagine I would like to do that after cutting my dataset according to time (which will require some posix-like functions (which I am not exactly sure which would be needed here, or how to use it).
4. And lastly, there is the question of visualization.  How do I create a tag cloud of the words?  I found [a solution for this here](http://www.r-bloggers.com/creating-tag-cloud-using-r-and-flash-javascript-swfobject/), any other suggestion/recommendations?

I believe I am asking a huge question here but I tried to break it to as many straightforward questions as possible.  Any help will be welcomed!

Best,

Tal

Comment: For what it's worth, I think that this should be broken up in to separate questions...

Comment: Thanks Shane, you think I should break it to 4 different questions out of it, or in a different way?  (thanks for your opinion)

Comment: I agree with Shane. As to the number of questions, look for technical and general concepts and put them each in a question. e.g. How do I create a word cloud in R? or When parsing text for key words what methods and packages are helpful in culling out the key words?

Comment: #2 about parsing: ask that question with a sample of data given. Any parsing question that does not include real data is like asking, "how do I get laid?" You'll get advice, but the probability of it helping you in real life is near zero.

Comment: #1 - you're going to get some folks, with names like "JD LONG" asking you if you've read the code to twitteR and if you've read the Twitter API documentation. You should read those first and then come back with specific questions. e.g.: how do services that return more than 1500 tweets get those results since Twitter caps the API at 1500? (I have no idea if 1500 is the right number)

Comment: @JD: Poetic commentary, as always!

Comment: Hello JD, thank you for the suggestions - I will implement them at full (except for your advice regarding "how do I get laid" - since I suspect that SO doesn't accepts porn images. :P)

Comment: @JD: The answer to "how do I get laid?" is, of course, to tell your object of desire how to parse data, complete with a commented, minimal, self-contained, reproducible example.

Answer (score 6):

- Word/Tag cloud in R using "snippets" package
- www.wordle.net
- Using openNLP package you could pos-tag the tweets(pos=Part of speech) and then extract just the nouns, verbs or adjectives for visualization in a wordcloud.
- Maybe you can query twitter and use the current system-time as a time-stamp, write to a local database and query again in increments of x secs/mins, etc.
- There is historical data available at http://www.readwriteweb.com/archives/twitter_data_dump_infochimp_puts_1b_connections_up.php and http://www.wired.com/epicenter/2010/04/loc-google-twitter/

Answer (score 2):

As for the plotting piece: I did a word cloud here: http://trends.techcrunch.com/2009/09/25/describe-yourself-in-3-or-4-words/ using the snippets package, my code is in there. I manually pulled out certain words. Check it out and let me know if you have more specific questions.

Answer (score 2):

I note that this is an old question, and there are several solutions available via web search, but here's one answer (via http://blog.ouseful.info/2012/02/15/generating-twitter-wordclouds-in-r-prompted-by-an-open-learning-blogpost/):

```
require(twitteR)
searchTerm='#dev8d'
#Grab the tweets
rdmTweets <- searchTwitter(searchTerm, n=500)
#Use a handy helper function to put the tweets into a dataframe
tw.df=twListToDF(rdmTweets)

##Note: there are some handy, basic Twitter related functions here:
##https://github.com/matteoredaelli/twitter-r-utils
#For example:
RemoveAtPeople <- function(tweet) {
  gsub("@\\w+", "", tweet)
}
#Then for example, remove @d names
tweets <- as.vector(sapply(tw.df$text, RemoveAtPeople))

##Wordcloud - scripts available from various sources; I used:
#http://rdatamining.wordpress.com/2011/11/09/using-text-mining-to-find-out-what-rdatamining-tweets-are-about/
#Call with eg: tw.c=generateCorpus(tw.df$text)
generateCorpus= function(df,my.stopwords=c()){
  #Install the textmining library
  require(tm)
  #The following is cribbed and seems to do what it says on the can
  tw.corpus= Corpus(VectorSource(df))
  # remove punctuation
  tw.corpus = tm_map(tw.corpus, removePunctuation)
  #normalise case
  tw.corpus = tm_map(tw.corpus, tolower)
  # remove stopwords
  tw.corpus = tm_map(tw.corpus, removeWords, stopwords('english'))
  tw.corpus = tm_map(tw.corpus, removeWords, my.stopwords)

  tw.corpus
}

wordcloud.generate=function(corpus,min.freq=3){
  require(wordcloud)
  doc.m = TermDocumentMatrix(corpus, control = list(minWordLength = 1))
  dm = as.matrix(doc.m)
  # calculate the frequency of words
  v = sort(rowSums(dm), decreasing=TRUE)
  d = data.frame(word=names(v), freq=v)
  #Generate the wordcloud
  wc=wordcloud(d$word, d$freq, min.freq=min.freq)
  wc
}

print(wordcloud.generate(generateCorpus(tweets,'dev8d'),7))

##Generate an image file of the wordcloud
png('test.png', width=600,height=600)
wordcloud.generate(generateCorpus(tweets,'dev8d'),7)
dev.off()

#We could make it even easier if we hide away the tweet grabbing code. eg:
tweets.grabber=function(searchTerm,num=500){
  require(twitteR)
  rdmTweets = searchTwitter(searchTerm, n=num)
  tw.df=twListToDF(rdmTweets)
  as.vector(sapply(tw.df$text, RemoveAtPeople))
}
#Then we could do something like:
tweets=tweets.grabber('ukgc12')
wordcloud.generate(generateCorpus(tweets),3)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to answer your question in making big word cloud.
What I did is

> 1. Use s0.tweet <- searchTwitter(KEYWORD,n=1500) for 7 days or more, such as [THIS](http://blog.cloudstat.org/post/18296357801/r-twitter-analysis-how-hot-is-the-lynas-rare-earths-mini).
> 2. Combine them by this command :
>
> rdmTweets = c(s0.tweet,s1.tweet,s2.tweet,s3.tweet,s4.tweet,s5.tweet,s6.tweet,s7.tweet)

The result:

[image: Lynas Square Cloud]

This Square Cloud consists of about 9000 tweets.

Source: [People voice about Lynas Malaysia through Twitter Analysis with R CloudStat](http://blog.cloudstat.org/post/18451446920/people-voice-about-lynas-malaysia-through-twitter-analys)

Hope it help!