# Is there a dynamic word/tag cloud Java API somewhere?

Tags: java, r, graphics, visualization, tag-cloud

There are loads of great word and tag clouds available, the most prominent being [wordle.net](http://wordle.net).  But I am looking to display something akin to what some folks did for a [twitter replay of the 2010 world cup](http://twitdom.com/world-cup-2010-twitter-replay/), just not using flash.  I'm not too familiar with R, but it seems to be the best tool for generating some statistical decay of font size over time.  Is there a Java API (or combination of APIs) that might make this capability easier from the start?

Comment: Here's an article on using R to generate word clouds: http://onertipaday.blogspot.com/2011/07/word-cloud-in-r.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not aware of a good R package for that. There are some functions, like `cloud` in the [snippets](http://www.rforge.net/doc/packages/snippets/00Index.html) package, and maybe other functions, but nothing compared to http://wordle.net, http://tagcrowd.com/, or [Many Eyes](http://www-958.ibm.com/software/data/cognos/manyeyes/page/Visualization_Options.html). [Drew Conway](http://www.drewconway.com/zia/?p=2624) has done some nice stuff with `tm` + `ggplot2`; I also played with it a while ago, but this was more of to play with 3D tag cloud (with `rgl`) than wordle.

[image]

In Python or Processing, there are some ongoing projects detailed on this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/342687/algorithm-to-implement-something-like-wordle). To my knowledge, [Tagxedo](http://www.tagxedo.com/) looks great but it has no API and it relies on Silverlight.

Pierre Lindenbaum also has some Java code, see his blog post [Playing with the Wordle algorithm: a tag cloud of Mesh Terms](http://plindenbaum.blogspot.com/2010/10/playing-with-worldle-algorithm-tag.html).

Comment: Excellent sites.  However, these sites lack temporal capability, eg a sense that the weight of the word changes over time (as discrete frames).  I mentioned R because of this previous question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2961325/plotting-a-word-cloud-by-date-for-a-twitter-search-result-using-r).  I tried with Gephi, but the dynamic (temporal) capability is not yet mature enough (or my knowledge isn't, one or the other).

Comment: I just wanna make fancy and more dynamic word cloud. Please see an example  on https://www.wordyup.com/. But I dont know jquery. I work on R. Please share any idea how to make such.

Answer (score 0):

It's not great, but there is an open-source project (alas, in PHP) that does word clouds over time. The example uses presidential speeches. 
http://chir.ag/projects/preztags/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one that I created in Java as part of a larger project for deriving information from unstructured data : https://github.com/regunathb/Sift. The "tagcloud" project has all the required classes for generating a tag cloud and writing it to multiple putput image formats.