# Get total count of tweets from a API search result?

Tags: api, search, twitter, count

Hello Guy's I'm trying to count all of the tweets from a Twitter search API response, anyone got any ideas?

Everything I tried doesn't seem to work, I'm doing everything with jSON so my best guess is get the max_id and subtract the id from the first item in the object. But I think that's not giving me a correct number.

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing you can't do that: the twitter api docs don't show anything and you can see [Count number of results for a particular word on Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/580369/count-number-of-results-for-a-particular-word-on-twitter) for more detail.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Femi, I'm aware of that but I'm getting results with less than 15000. Because is not just one work on the search it must match a couple I'm guessing the jSON response is not throwing more than 3 pages (at 100 count) meaning 300 total, but this vary from search to search. That's what I would kike to count. :)

Comment: Well, the max_id / first id won't work, because you can't assume that the results are in order and in any case the max_id is just the largest id on the current page of the search results. If you're trying to count how many pages are available I don't think there's really any way to do it other than request all the pages and see where it returns no more data.

Comment: Figured it out.. thanks though..

I'm looping trough the available pages, and store the amount returned by the data.results jSON in a variable then count it's length :)

A note to other users I'm only doing this because my searches are really granular never > 350 else it wouldn't be a good idea since you will always get 15000 tops as seen on the link supplied by Femi.